# Question about position of words in a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality, standard-german, spoken-language, written-language

> Also ich habe es geschafft

or

> Also habe ich es geschafft

To me the second one sounds more like a question. And first one would be a more "spoken way".

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is only valid if *also* is refers to *ich*:

> Also **ich** habe es geschafft.

which roughly means "**I** made it (but maybe others did not)."

This way, *Also* and *ich* together are the first part of the sentence, followed by the verb. Otherwise, the verb-second rule would be violated.

In the second sentence, *also* applies to the statement as a whole. Here, *also* is the first part of the sentence, followed by the verb.

Comment: I agree, but also is an attribute? Also das würde mich sehr wundern

Comment: It's not an adjective. I changed the wording to avoid this misunderstanding.

Comment: _also_ in the first sentence is a constituent separate from the subject _ich_, and it functions as a sentential adverb – it refers and modifies the whole sentence. I'm not fully fluent with German grammatical terminology, but if I remember correctly, the slot that is occupied by _also_ is the "Vorvorfeld" to distinguish it from the slot "Vorfeld" that precedes the verb. The "Vorvorfeld" isn't considered a violation of verb-second word order .

Comment: @Schmuddi I disagree. "Zero-position" works with a word like *denn*, but not with *also*.

Comment: What's the justification for your claim that _also_ and _ich_ form a single constituent that's in the "Vorfeld", then? The usual criteria of constituents (e.g. mobility, coordination, syntactic independence) won't work on [_also ich_].

Comment: On second thoughts, I do withdraw my claim that _also_ is a sentence adverb. But I retain that it's (a) in the "Vorvorfeld" and (b) separate from _ich_.

Answer (score 2):

Also has a different meaning in those cases. The first one translates to: well, I made it.
The Second one: therefore I made it.

Answer (score 1):

As a conjunctive adverb with a consecutive meaning, similar to *folglich* or *deshalb*, *also* can appear in the first position of declarative sentences.

> Ich denke, also bin ich.
> *I think, therefore I am.*
>
> Die Arbeit hat mir nicht gefallen, also habe ich gekündigt.
> *I didn't like the work, so I quit.*
>
> Es nicht zu schaffen, war keine Option. Also habe ich es geschafft.
> *Not making it wasn't an option. Therefore, I made it.*

The last example can be used as a 'declarative question', spoken with a rising intonation. Imaging a teacher telling a student how many points he got in the exam and the student being unsure whether he passed or not:

> Also habe ich es geschafft?
> *So I made it?*

In its other uses, *also* precedes the sentence and doesn't change its meaning. It is used as a marker of initiating or continuing an utterance.

> Also, gehen wir jetzt?
> *So, are we leaving now?*
>
> Also zumindest ich habe es geschafft, aber ich weiß nicht, ob die anderen es auch geschafft haben.
> *Well, at least I made it, but I don't know whether the others did, too.*